# Printing all possible combinations of elements in an array

Tags: c, recursion

During recursion, once elements are changed in an array, this change persist. How to pass array so that changes are done according to the call stack ?
Once element at index 2 is set, its set in every function call.

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void recur(int flag[], int n, int idx){
    if(idx==n){
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            if(flag[i])
                printf("%d  ", i);
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    recur(flag, n, idx+1);
    flag[idx] = 1;
    recur(flag, n, idx+1);
}
int main(){
    int flag[] = {0, 0, 0};
    recur(flag, 3, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the following output:

```
2
1 2
1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: What did you want to get?

Comment: "all possible combinations of elements" seems descriptive enough

Comment: Also see: powerset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the array intact, you need to revert any changes to the array you've made in your function. In this case you should store in a temporary variable the value of `flag[idx]` before changing it and then restore it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void recur(int flag[], int n, int idx) {
  if (idx == n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (flag[i]) {
        printf("%d  ", i);
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
  }

  recur(flag, n, idx + 1);
  int temp = flag[idx];  // Change line 1
  flag[idx] = 1;
  recur(flag, n, idx + 1);
  flag[idx] = temp;  // Change line 2
}

int main() {
  int flag[] = {0, 0, 0};
  recur(flag, 3, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

See it in ideone: https://ideone.com/Q6Vb7A